# A question on the idea of curvature of Riemann

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

In the book [Mathematical Masterpieces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387330615), chapter 3, section 1, the authors have talked about the curvature and the ideas around it.

They wrote

> If the curvature is given in $\dfrac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ surface directions at every point, then the metric relations of the manifold may be determined.

Could you please explain for me what did they mean? I can't understand what is **$\dfrac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ surface directions at every point**

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide slightly more context?  Maybe provide the entire paragraph leading up to the troubling sentence? Not all of us have that particular book...

Comment: In a space of $n$ dimensions there are $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ planes between the $n$ coordinate axis. I have the impression this might have something to do with the claim.

Comment: As Rogelio pointed out, $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ is the number of linearly independent 2-planes in the tangent space. However, specifying the sectional curvatures on these 2-planes is *not* enough to determine the full Riemannian curvature in general - if we take a basis of bivectors $w_i$ and attempt to apply the polarization formula we find that we also need the curvatures of $w_i + w_j$. I'm also unsure what the authors mean by the "metric relations".

Comment: The statement in the book is indeed very sloppy. The answer, I think, is to read dither hung else. For instance, Spivak spends great deal of time explaining how curvature determines the metric.

Comment: On the other hand, there might be an interesting problem here: If an open n-ball is equipped with $n(n-1)/2$ 2-d distributions so that at every point they form coordinate 2-planes and two Riemannian metrics have the same sectional curvatures along these distributions then the metrics are locally isometric. I guess, one needs $n>3$ for this to work and maybe non-flatness condition.